# how to create a doc file in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I like to create a word i.e.(*.doc) file in VB.Net.
I know how to create that by adding a com object to our project.
But i don't want that because, some might not use MS Word, like i myself use Open Office and not MS Office. So at that time it will give error.

I already developed a application on creating PDF file without adding com Ref to my Project.
I used itextsharp.dll to create PDF file which is a Open source.

So is their any dll which is open source and help me to create doc file.
Or
Is their any other way to create Doc file.

Comment: What kind of solution are you developing? Web application? desktop application? 
Wich version of MS Office or Open Office are you targeting?
All these information will be usefull to give you a more aimed answer

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the COM object and **include it in the project's binaries**. This way, when you install it on a client's machine, they don't have to have any of the required dlls. Your app will generate the .doc files. And I believe OpenOffice can read those files.